# Using smart phone, how to make phone call using google voice number?

Tags: google-voice, motorola

I have an Android phone (Motorola E) with the official Google Voice app installed.

I always give people my Google voice number. For this reason, when I call people I need my google voice number to appear instead of my real mobile number so that they recognize me.

However, when I turn on "Always use Google voice to make call" in the GVoice app, the number that makes the call is some other number (my guess is a number created by Google) and NOT my GVoice number.

I've tried to do this for a long time but in vain. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the number that is making the call (initiated) is a random number, be assured the number that shows on their caller id is your google voice number, unless you have a different setting in your voice.google.com set up or on your phone.

I noticed mine did this too when i called out from my phone the other day, but my client saw my gv number

Chad

Comment: I just tested this and it's true. Do you have a similar solution regarding texting? Is it possible to text people with only Google Voice number? (Bonus point if we can do it via our cellular texting plan instead of data plan.)